# Identify this roadside plant in Montserrat, Spain

Tags: species-identification, flowers

Photographed in April; growing abundantly on the side of a rocky path in Montserrat, Spain.  Up to maybe 1 foot (30 cm) in height.

[image][image]

Comment: The blackish "eye-like" objects seem to be cyathium inflorescence, a sort of "false flower" found in the genus *Euphorbia*.

Comment: The genus *Euphorbia* is bizarre in the sense its species are very different-looking, and often impossible to correlate from superficial shape

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This plant is in the genus [*Euphorbia,*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphorbia) which is a large and diverse group.  The members take wildly different forms, but the general form of this plant is shared by many *Euphorbia* members.  I'm not sure of the species, but think it is most likely Mediterranean Spurge, [*Euphorbia characias*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphorbia_characias):

[image] Photo: [Macro63](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Euphorbia_characias_1_.JPG)

[image] Photo: [cc-by-sa-2.0 Bernard Dupont.](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Mediterranean_Spurge_(Euphorbia_characias)_(8347193302).jpg)